# How to get the argument for promise::set_exception(x)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, c++11, promise

I found in several places on how a *promise* should be used references to `copy_exception`, but I can not find it in the current FDIS. Is there an alternative way on how to use `set_exception()` since those blogs?

For example [here](https://bartoszmilewski.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/broken-promises-c0x-futures/)

```
void asyncFun(promise<int> intPromise)
{
    int result;
    try {
        // calculate the result
        intPromise.set_value(result);
    } catch (MyException e) {
        intPromise.set_exception(std::copy_exception(e));  // <- copy
    }
}
```

I find `std::current_exception()` [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html).

```
catch(...)
{
    p.set_exception(std::current_exception());
}
```

Therefore my questions:

- **Should I always use `current_exception()`, even when I do not catch "`...`"?**
- **Or is there new a different name for `copy_exception`?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a different name for `copy_exception`.  `copy_exception` was renamed late in the standardization process over confusion of what it actually did:

```
template<class E>
   exception_ptr make_exception_ptr(E e) noexcept;
```

> *Effects*: Creates an `exception_ptr` object that refers to a copy of
>   `e`, ...

Use of either `make_exception_ptr` or `current_exception` is fine, depending on what exception you're trying to set.